# Asyncio module failing to create task

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

My Source Code:

```
import asyncio

async def mycoro(number):
    print(f'Starting {number}')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f'Finishing {number}')
    return str(number)

c = mycoro(3)
task = asyncio.create_task(c)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(task)
loop.close()
```

Error:

```
RuntimeError: no running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'mycoro' was never awaited
```

I was watching a tutorial and according to my code it was never awaited when I did and it clearly does in the video I was watching.

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: What is the name of your source code file?

Comment: Your recent edit has completely changed the error message. Which error do you actually want help on?

Comment: I fixed the other problem it was my file name.

Comment: Please avoid changing the goal of your question. If your problem is solved and a new one appears, ask a new question.

Comment: I can only ask questions every 90 minutes .

Comment: Are you able to supply where you got the code from?

Answer (score 3):

Simply run the coroutine directly without creating a task for it:

```py
import asyncio

async def mycoro(number):
    print(f'Starting {number}')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f'Finishing {number}')
    return str(number)

c = mycoro(3)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(c)
loop.close()
```

The purpose of [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) is to create an *additional* task *from inside a running* task. Since it directly starts the new task, it must be used *inside* a running event loop – hence the error when using it outside.

Use [`loop.create_task(c)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task) if a task must be created from outside a task.

---

In more recent version of `asyncio`, use [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) to avoid having to handle the event loop explicitly:

```py
c = mycoro(3)
asyncio.run(c)
```

In general, use `asyncio.create_task` only to *increase* concurrency. Avoid using it when another task would block immediately.

```py
# bad task usage: concurrency stays the same due to blocking
async def bad_task():
    task = asyncio.create_task(mycoro(0))
    await task

# no task usage: concurrency stays the same due to stacking
async def no_task():
     await mycoro(0)

# good task usage: concurrency is increased via multiple tasks
async def good_task():
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(mycoro(i)) for i in range(3)]
    print('Starting done, sleeping now...')
    await asyncio.sleep(1.5)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  # ensure subtasks finished
```

Comment: This doesn't answer how to use create_task? Also loop should not be used, when you can do asyncio.run()

Comment: @Greg The question is not "how to use create_task".

Comment: *The purpose of asyncio.create_task is to create an additional task from a running task.* - this is a bit unclear, did you mean "from a coroutine"? Also, perhaps the answer should mention that the immediate problem is that `asyncio.create_task()` requires being invoked from inside a running loop. While redundant, the OP's usage was correct, and had they used `loop.create_task(c)` instead of `asyncio.create_task(c)`, would have worked.

Comment: @user4815162342 I don't think "from a running task" is incorrect, since ``asyncio`` can run more than just coroutines. As for the others, you are correct – I've tried to add both pieces of information now.

Comment: Hmm. As far as I know, `create_task()` (unlike `ensure_future()`) doesn't accept arbitrary awaitables, but just coroutines. Also, "from a running task" sounds like it accepts a task and returns a (different?) task - that's why I thought it was unclear.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you meant! By "from a running task", you didn't refer to the argument passed to `create_task()`, but to the position where it is invoked! (Your subsequent sentence actually makes it clear, but I missed it on first reading.) I would suggest "from inside a running task" to avoid confusion.

Comment: If you update mycoro() to sleep for 2 second, then it looks like good_task() won't print 'Finishing.. ' as theres no await.

Comment: @Greg ``good_task`` never prints `Finishing`, `mycoro` does. When just using ``asyncio.run(good_task())`` or ``loop.run_until_complete(good_task())``, one explicitly tells asyncio not to wait for child tasks – thus aborting every task after ``good_task`` completes. Whether this is desirable or not depends on the use-case – for example, if ``mycoro`` represents some background tasks running indefinitely killing it implicitly is simpler than coordinating shutdown.

Answer (score -2):

**Change the line**

```
task = asyncio.Task(c)
```

Comment: There is no create_task attribute in the asyncio module.
Check this dir(asyncio).

Comment: yes there is https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task

Comment: But it's not working. If we use ensure_future it's working fine.
My Python  version is 3.6.10 , so It won't work. Thanks for mention it.
Check your python version @cashcash.

Comment: I'm running 3.8.